# Creating a table with centered images inside cells and rotated labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, rotating

[image]

I would like to fix the table above so that:

1. The figures are vertically centered (as well as the "Low" and "High" labels)
2. The right-hand figures do not clip the upper dividing lines
3. The outer labels (i.e., "This is the x-axis" and "This is the y-axis") are centered via-a-vis the inner labels (e.g., "This is the x-axis" is centered with respect to "Left" and "Right"; same with "This is the y-axis")
4. Ideally, the code should work with figures of arbitrary sizes (i.e., without requiring manual adjustments)

The LaTeX code producing the table is this:

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \cline{3-4}
  \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{This is the $y$-axis}} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{High}   & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{fig.jpg}
} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\includegraphics[scale=0.65]{fig.jpg}} \\
  \cline{3-4}
                      & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Low}  & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{fig.jpg}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{fig.jpg}} \\
  \cline{3-4}
                      &       & Left     &     Right \\
                      &       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{This is the $x$-axis} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

And the example figure (fig.jpg) used is this:

[image: fig.jpg]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with a `TikZ matrix`. It solves the problem for vertical and horizontal figures aligning and also solve the problem with axis labels, because these can be placed as two `label` nodes.

The main problem is how to draw border lines, because `matrix` only places nodes, but they keep its real size and borders. Therefore, once `matrix` is finished, we need some commands to draw vertical and horizontal lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,
column sep=2mm, row sep=2mm, nodes={anchor=center},
column 1/.style={nodes={anchor=center, rotate=90}},
row 3/.style={nodes={anchor=base}},
label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left:This is the $y$-axis}, 
label={below:This is the $x$-axis}]
{
High & \includegraphics[scale=.25]{fig.jpg} & \includegraphics[scale=.65]{fig.jpg} \\
Low & \includegraphics[scale=.25]{fig.jpg} & \includegraphics[scale=.35]{fig.jpg} \\
& Left & Right\\
};

\draw (A-1-3.north east) rectangle (A-1-2.west|-A-2-3.south);
\path (A-1-2.east) -- coordinate (aux1) (A-1-3.west);
\path (A-1-3.south) -- coordinate (aux2) (A-2-3.north);

\draw (A-1-3.north-|aux1)--(A-2-3.south-|aux1);
\draw (A-2-2.west|-aux2)--(A-1-3.east|-aux2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

For #3, we can suppress `matrix labels` (which center according the whole matrix size) and use regular nodes (with `positioning` library) placed with references to rows and columns labels:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,
column sep=2mm, row sep=2mm, nodes={anchor=center},
column 1/.style={nodes={anchor=center, rotate=90}},
row 3/.style={nodes={anchor=base}}]
{
High & \includegraphics[scale=.25]{fig.jpg} & \includegraphics[scale=.65]{fig.jpg} \\
Low & \includegraphics[scale=.25]{fig.jpg} & \includegraphics[scale=.35]{fig.jpg} \\
& Left & Right\\
};

\path (A-1-1) -- node[rotate=90, left=5mm, anchor=center] {This is the $y$-axis} (A-2-1);
\path (A-3-2) -- node[below=5mm, anchor=center] {This is the $x$-axis} (A-3-3);

\draw (A-1-3.north east) rectangle (A-1-2.west|-A-2-3.south);
\path (A-1-2.east) -- coordinate (aux1) (A-1-3.west);
\path (A-1-3.south) -- coordinate (aux2) (A-2-3.north);

\draw (A-1-3.north-|aux1)--(A-2-3.south-|aux1);
\draw (A-2-2.west|-aux2)--(A-1-3.east|-aux2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very good.  Thank you.  For my needs, the only issue remaining is requirement #3 (that the outer labels are centered with respect to the inner labels; e.g., "This is the x-axis" to be exactly in between "Left" and "Right").

Comment: @scaramouche Answer updated with axis labels centered respect row and column labels.

Answer (score 2):

That can be done with a `\raisebox` and the `cellspace` package for vertical padding. Here it is:

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,multirow}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc|Sc|Sc|}
  \cline{3-4}
  \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{This is the $y$-axis}} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{High} & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ball.jpg}} & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{ball.jpg}} \\
  \cline{3-4}
    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{High} & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ball.jpg}} & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{ball.jpg}} \\
  \cline{3-4}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Small} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Large} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{This is the $x$-axis} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is very nice.  It has only one problem for what I need: if the sizes of the balls change, the outer x- and y-axes cease to be centered (e.g., try setting the scale parameter of just one of balls to `scale=0.95`).  Is there a way to have the outer axes automatically centered, no matter the size of the balls?

Comment: I have edited the question to make this requirement clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately no, as `\multirow{2} {…}` merges 2 cells which are supposed to have 1 line. You have to use the optional argument  to have a manual adjustment (preferably in `ex`, not in absolute units). I tried an automatic solution using `\pst-node`, but irt seems to be conflicting the `tabular` environment. Perhaps with the TikZ analog, `tikzmark`. The idea  was to put two (empty) nodes on the base line of each row, and join them with an invisible rule and a label along this rule. Unfortunately, I know  very little of TikZ, and don't know how to do it.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll add `tikz` as one of the tags of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the other answers have addressed point #3, here is a ConTeXt solution that uses page anchors. The basic idea is to set anchors at the words "High" and "Low" and then use position graphics to draw "This is $y$-axis" at the mid point of these two anchors.

```
\useexternalfigure[ball][https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ap04.jpg]
\startsetups align
  \setupTABLE[align={lohi,middle},offset=0.25em]
  \setupTABLE[column][first][frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[row][last][frame=off]
\stopsetups

\defineframedtext
  [labels]
  [background=labels,
   loffset=1.5\lineheight,
   roffset=0pt,
   boffset=1.5\lineheight,
   toffset=0pt,
   width=fit,
   offset=overlay,
   frame=off,
  ]

\startMPinclusions
  input mp-abck.mpiv;
\stopMPinclusions

\defineoverlay[labels][\positionoverlay{labels}]

\startpositionoverlay{labels}
  \setMPpositiongraphic{high}{y:label}{to=low}
  \setMPpositiongraphic{left}{x:label}{to=right}
\stoppositionoverlay

\startMPpositiongraphic{y:label}
  newpair p, q;
  initialize_box(\MPpos{\MPvar{self}}); p := 0.5[llxy, ulxy];
  initialize_box(\MPpos{\MPvar{to}});   q := 0.5[llxy, ulxy];

  label.lft("\rotate{This is $y$-axis}", 0.5[p,q] - (0.5LineHeight,0));
  anchor_box(\MPanchor{\MPvar{self}});
\stopMPpositiongraphic

\startMPpositiongraphic{x:label}
  newpair p, q;
  initialize_box(\MPpos{\MPvar{self}}); p := 0.5[llxy, lrxy];
  initialize_box(\MPpos{\MPvar{to}});   q := 0.5[llxy, lrxy];

  label.bot("This is $x$-axis", 0.5[p,q] - (0,0.5LineHeight));
  anchor_box(\MPanchor{\MPvar{self}});
\stopMPpositiongraphic


\starttext
\startlabels
\startTABLE[setups=align]
  \NC \hpos{high}{\rotate{High}}
  \NC \dontleavehmode\externalfigure[ball][width=1.5cm]
  \NC \dontleavehmode\externalfigure[ball][width=5.5cm]
  \NC \NR
  \NC \hpos{low}{\rotate{Low}}
  \NC \dontleavehmode\externalfigure[ball][width=1.5cm]
  \NC \dontleavehmode\externalfigure[ball][width=2.5cm]
  \NC \NR
  \NC \NC \hpos{left}{Left} \NC \hpos{right}{Right} \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoplabels
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Here are the results for a few different sizes of the balls:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Many thanks.  This works well.  I accepted the other answer, as it is shorter and does not rely on ConTeXt (which I am not very familiar with).